# How to see the IP address on OPENEULER?

Tags: virtualbox, ip

enter code hereI am a beginner in [OPENEULER OS](https://www.openeuler.org/en/) and trying to get my IPv4 address on OPENEULER operating system to do some configurations on putty but it get me this result:

[image: img1]

and putty get me this error:

[image: img2]

Normally it should be something like this (I know that this is another OS but I think the concept still the same):

[image: img3]

(note:I am working on VirtualBox)

I have checked DHCP:

[image: dhcpcheck]

I think it is enabled , and about virtual box I will screen shots here

[image: vbox screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please don't post textual output as images. From image it's not possible to for example copy text for a search term, and images can be hard to see in various situations. Also if you do post an image, please don't screenshot the full screen unless the full area has something relevant. Only screenshot the active window. Instead of posting an image, just copy the actual text and paste it to your question. Surround it with the code brackets `{ }` on the top of the question box to preserve formatting.

Comment: Based on the images; have you installed DHCP client, and is it running? Please don't answer in comments, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771848/edit) the question instead. That way it stays up-to-date with your situation and all relevant info is readily available. I tried to see how this works in openEULER, but it seems that all documentation is in Chinese, which I don't speak. As this is a specialized OS, I think your best bet would be to put the question to [openEULER community](https://datastat.openeuler.org/en/overview).

Comment: Of course you can simply configure a static IP address instead of using DHCP. Again can't help you there due to language barrier. Usually this kind of basic how-to is in the OS documentation.

Comment: You're checking the IP address correctly. You just don't have an IP address - this might be a result of how virtualbox *or* the client OS is set up. You'd want to share your virtualbox settings, and ideally the network configuration - I think in this case it ought to be network manager based but I'm not sure.

Comment: @user1778417 - You're welcome :-) If you have new info to add, or if you answer a question, you shouldn't post an answer or comment. Better way is to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771848/edit) the question instead as I now did for you. That way it stays up-to-date and all relevant info is readily available. As a new member of the community, it's a good idea to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and check the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com\help) to learn how these sites work.

Comment: thanks a lot guys for your answers ,about the DHCP I have checked it [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZJJb.png) I think it is enabled , and about virtual box I will screen shots here hope that will resolve the problem [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W0Ij.png)